# VMWare как настроить сеть на виртуальной машине?

Tags: сервер, сеть, vmware, виртуализация

Создаю виртуальную машину в VMWare ESXi 5.5, windows 2008 r2, прописываю MAC адрес, устанавливаю net framework, прописываю в настройках содинения с интернетом IP address, Subnet mask, Default gateway, DNS адреса. Пробую подключиться к машине через Remote Desktop Connection, не подключается, от машины даже откликов нет. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Причин может быть уйма. Приведите хотя-бы настройки виртуальных сетей на гипервизоре. Проврьте имена vmnetwork если их несколько.

Comment: @dimka3210 , это не virtualbox, это ESXi

Answer (score 1):

1. В случае если сервер в домене, то есть вариант запрета ответа на ping политикой домена.
2. Часто причиной отсутствия сетевого обнаружения служит заботливый антивирус.
3. По умолчанию RDP протокол закрыт брандмауэром, необходимо добавить правила в исключения для порта (по умолчанию 3389, его редко используют из-за проблем с безопасностью).
4. По личному опыту, чаще всего проблема с настройками шлюза и виртуальной сети. Проверьте ваш виртуальный коммутатор и шлюз. Для проверки можно создать 2 виртуальную машину и проверить соединение между ними.
5. Для Esxi и виртуальных машин неплохо было бы иметь DHCP сервер, по его работе можно точнее сделать выводы о проблеме.